# Docker-compose ps showing Docker names with directory-prefix instead of projectname-prefix

Tags: docker, docker-compose

What could be the reason that in docker-compose ps the names are showing as workspace_ instead of projectname_?

The Jenkins job is executed from /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/build-docker-images/branches/feature-Jenkinsfile.fap3np/workspace, so appearently it's still using the directory workspace_ as a prefix in some places.

Is this behaviour expected to happen? Why is that?

```
+ COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME=denpal docker-compose up -d --build
Creating network "denpal_default" with the default driver
Building cli
...
Creating denpal_mariadb_1 ...
Creating denpal_redis_1   ...
Creating denpal_cli_1     ...
Creating denpal_solr_1    ...
[5A[2K
Creating denpal_redis_1   ... [32mdone[0m
[5B[1A[2K
Creating denpal_solr_1    ... [32mdone[0m
[1B[6A[2K
Creating denpal_cli_1     ... [32mdone[0m
[6BCreating denpal_nginx_1   ...
Creating denpal_php_1     ...
[7A[2K
Creating denpal_mariadb_1 ... [32mdone[0m
[7B[4A[2K
Creating denpal_nginx_1   ... [32mdone[0m
[4BCreating denpal_varnish_1 ...
[2A[2K
Creating denpal_php_1     ... [32mdone[0m
[2B[3A[2K
Creating denpal_varnish_1 ... [32mdone[0m
[3B+ docker-compose ps
       Name                      Command               State            Ports
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
workspace_cli_1       /sbin/tini -- /lagoon/entr ...   Up      9000/tcp
workspace_mariadb_1   /sbin/tini -- /lagoon/entr ...   Up      0.0.0.0:32771->3306/tcp
workspace_nginx_1     /sbin/tini -- /lagoon/entr ...   Up      8080/tcp
workspace_php_1       /sbin/tini -- /lagoon/entr ...   Up      9000/tcp
workspace_redis_1     /sbin/tini -- /lagoon/entr ...   Up      6379/tcp
workspace_solr_1      /sbin/tini -- /lagoon/entr ...   Up      0.0.0.0:32770->8983/tcp
workspace_varnish_1   /sbin/tini -- /lagoon/entr ...   Up      8080/tcp

+ docker ps
+ head
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                                COMMAND                  CREATED              STATUS                       PORTS                                                                                        NAMES
63ded7e931bc        varnish-drupal                              "/sbin/tini -- /lago…"   About a minute ago   Up About a minute            8080/tcp                                                                                     denpal_varnish_1
63a377935929        denpal_php                                           "/sbin/tini -- /lago…"   About a minute ago   Up About a minute            9000/tcp                                                                                     denpal_php_1
a01180c2f378        denpal_nginx                                         "/sbin/tini -- /lago…"   About a minute ago   Up About a minute            8080/tcp                                                                                     denpal_nginx_1
a27a34d0d266        mariadb-drupal                              "/sbin/tini -- /lago…"   About a minute ago   Up About a minute            0.0.0.0:32779->3306/tcp                                                                      denpal_mariadb_1
932647378b9d        denpal                                               "/sbin/tini -- /lago…"   About a minute ago   Up About a minute            9000/tcp                                                                                     denpal_cli_1
9bb188c80a4c        solr:6.6-drupal                             "/sbin/tini -- /lago…"   About a minute ago   Up About a minute            0.0.0.0:32778->8983/tcp                                                                      denpal_solr_1
6e5a7b68631b        redis                                       "/sbin/tini -- /lago…"   About a minute ago   Up About a minute            6379/tcp                                                                                     denpal_redis_1

+ docker-compose ps
       Name                      Command               State            Ports
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
workspace_cli_1       /sbin/tini -- /lagoon/entr ...   Up      9000/tcp
workspace_mariadb_1   /sbin/tini -- /lagoon/entr ...   Up      0.0.0.0:32771->3306/tcp
workspace_nginx_1     /sbin/tini -- /lagoon/entr ...   Up      8080/tcp
workspace_php_1       /sbin/tini -- /lagoon/entr ...   Up      9000/tcp
workspace_redis_1     /sbin/tini -- /lagoon/entr ...   Up      6379/tcp
workspace_solr_1      /sbin/tini -- /lagoon/entr ...   Up      0.0.0.0:32770->8983/tcp
workspace_varnish_1   /sbin/tini -- /lagoon/entr ...   Up      8080/tcp
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use -p to change the prefix name, using the projects base directory for the prefix is default behavior https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/envvars/